# Understanding Theorem $7$.$23$ of Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

The Theorem states the following:

(a) If $ u\in D'(\mathbb{R^n})$ has its support in $rB$, if $u$ has order $N$ and if $f(z)=u(e_{-z})$ where $z \in \mathbb{C^n}$, then $f$ is entire, the resriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ is the Fourier transform of $u$, and there is a constant $\gamma \lt \infty$ such that $$|f(z)| \le \gamma(1+|z|)^Ne^{r|\text{Im}z|} $$

(b) Conversely, if $f$ is an entire function in $\mathbb{C^n}$ which satisfies the above inequality for some $N$ and some $\gamma$, then there exists $u \in D'(\mathbb{R^n})$, with support in $rB$, such that $f(z)=u(e_{-z})$

In Proving (a), the problem arises when $f$ is shown continuous. I don't understand the line : $\text{If $w \to z$ in $\mathbb{C^n}$, then $e_{-w} \to e_{-z}$ in $\mathbb{C^\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $u$ is continuous on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$ }$. What does it mean by $e_{-w} \to e_{-z}$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$ and  $u$ being continuous on $\mathbb{C^\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$??

Then Why is it enough to show that $$g(\lambda)=f(a+b\lambda)=u(e_{-a-\lambda b})$$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C^n}$ is entire , to prove that $f$ is entire??

Again I do't understand these lines: $\text{Since $\lambda \to e_{-a-\lambda b}$ is continuous from $\mathbb{C}$ to $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, the $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$-valued integral $F=\int_{\Gamma}e_{-a-b\lambda} d\lambda$ is welldefined. Evaluation at any $t \in \mathbb{R^n}$ is a continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$. It therefore commutes with the integral sign. Hence $F(t)=\int_{\Gamma}e_{-a-\lambda b}(t)d\lambda=0$}$

Thus $F=0$ and $0=u(F)=\int_{\Gamma}u(e_{-a-\lambda b}) d\lambda=\int_{\Gamma}g(\lambda) d\lambda$. Why can I take the integral sign out of $u$?? Then Morera's theorem gives that $g$ is entire.

Thanks for the help!!